# Problem creating iOS build file for Facebook app review

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook

I am following the procedures here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced#sim_build

I start by running the build on an iPhone 5s

Then I use (filling out all of the asterisks and destination) from the command line

```
ditto -ck --sequesterRsrc --keepParent `ls -1 -d -t ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*/Build/Products/*-iphonesimulator/*.app | head -n 1` path/to/YourApp.zip
```

And then

```
ios-sim launch /path/to/your-app.app
```

to launch the build, also from the command line and replacing the file path

I receive this error

```
/Users/planetsanzio/Desktop/MyApp.zip/Info.plist file not found.
```

Also, there is a greyed out 'x' over the file itself when viewed from Finder. The following error pops when the build file is double clicked

```
You can’t use this version of the application “Chain” with this version of macOS.
You have macOS 10.14.4. The application requires macOS 12.0 or later.
```

Where 12.0 is the iOS target version of the app. Whenever I try to upload the zip file to Facebook, it says there was an error trying to upload the file

Am I following the procedure correctly? Has anyone experienced this before?

NOTE - I am not using Cordova

Comment: Do you have multiple Xcode in your system?

Comment: No. I have 1 Xcode icon and have not previously tried to install more than one.

Comment: Are you pointing to a zip file? /Users/planetsanzio/Desktop/MyApp.zip? are you supposed to?

Comment: I am pointing to a zip file, the line "ios-sim launch /path/to/your-app.app" was copied right from the facebook guideline. I changed this to "ios-sim launch /Users/planetsanzio/Desktop/Chain.zip" before running the command

Answer (score 1):

Run the ios-sim launch command on the .app file, not the .zip file.

Facebook's review team will unzip the file first.